# Averaging a Column in a Named Range

Tags: vba, excel

complete and total newbie at this - but since my Excel VBA Programming for Dummies can't help, I was hoping you all might.

I have monthly evaluation scores for employees for various programs. The various programs are broken up into different workbooks. The data is different and the employee count fluctuates month to month, so I am trying to create formulas as relative as possible (ie. no specific cells) I repeat this function monthly and paste the rolling data into the workbook for posterity, so the row start changes as well as the number of rows for each month.

That said, I am using a named range ("April18") and I just need the average of one of the columns within "April18". I will most likely just change the named range each month and edit that within my macro.

Basically, how do I get the average of B:B within the named Range of "April18"

code:

```
 Do
    Dim x
    For x = 1 To 5
        ActiveCell.Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0\%"
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    Next x
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-5]:RC[-1])/100"
    Selection.Style = "Percent"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[-1]>85%,RC[-1]=85%),""Pass"",""Fail"")"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -6).Activate
Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use Application.WorksheetFunction.Index to get the column

```
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    Dim Sm as Double
    Sm = .Average(.Index(Range("April18"),0,2))
    Debug.Print Sm
End with
```

Where `2` is the column number of the named range you want.

Comment: Hi Scott  - thanks for the help! Unfortunately your calculation didn't work for me. I'm trying to get the average into the row below the last row in "April2018". I'm not sure if this changes your answer. I need to learn how to post the macro to see if that helps.

Comment: Just put the code in the original post using edit.  You then highlight it and hit Ctrl-k to format as code.  If you can't someone will help format it.

Comment: I should also say that I am already in the cell where I want the calculation using offset after my last calculation.

Comment: This is just an example you would simple assign the value in `Sm` to whatever cell you want.

Comment: Do not post code in comments, post it in the original post.

Comment: Got it. Appreciate the etiquette tutelage.